# How to specify correct report-task.txt file in SonarQube Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I am running a SonarQube analysis of my Node.js project in Jenkins. Sonar analysis creates report-task.txt file with the result. Unfortunately some modules in the node_modules folder also contain their report-task.txt files which results in a warning in Jenkins:

```
WARN: Found multiple 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Taking the first one.
/jenkins/workspace/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/some_module/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/some_other_module/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
```

Everything is fine until the Sonar analysis for my project fails: then Jenkins takes a different report-task.txt file from a module in node_modules as a result of a Sonar analysis:

```
WARN: Found multiple 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Taking the first one.
/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/some_module/.scannerwork/report-task.txt          <- wrong file
/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/some_other_module/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
```

Is there a way to specify that `/jenkins/workspace/.scannerwork/report-task.txt` is the only correct result file and Jenkins should ignore all the other? Preferably using Jenkins Pipelines

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from my pipeline:

```html
sh 'cat .scannerwork/report-task.txt'
// copy to a properties file so we can ingest as variables
sh 'cp .scannerwork/report-task.txt .scannerwork/report-task.properties'
def props = readProperties file: '.scannerwork/report-task.properties'
def ceTaskUrl= props['ceTaskUrl']
def sonarServerUrl=props['serverUrl']
// wait for analysis to complete
waitUntil {
    def response = httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', ignoreSslErrors: true, url: "${ceTaskUrl}", wrapAsMultipart: false
    println "Sent a request, got a $response response"
    def body = readJSON text: response.content
    body.each { key, value -> }
    ceTask = body.task.status
    echo "Status is "+ceTask
    if ("FAILED".equals(ceTask)){
    echo "failed = "+ceTask
    throw new Exception(failed+" Sonar process failed!")
    }
    return "SUCCESS".equals(ceTask)
    sleep 30
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).